# Android filewriter is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, filewriter

My app can collect some data and I just want to output these data to a txt file in SD card.

For some reason, the following code works on the Galaxy but not on the Nexus. I guess there is some thing wrong with the code.

```
//name of the file
        String name = "rawData " + year +
                "-" + month + "-" + date + "- " + hour + ":" + minute+ ".txt";

        // create a folder stores all the txt file.
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "rawData");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

        // creates a file and a file writer
        File gpxfile = new File(root, name);
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            Log.d(TAG, "The writer is created");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Is the writer null? " + writer);
```

[image: Here is the logcat]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

change this

`File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "rawData");`

to  `File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Answer (score 0):

External storage is usually a fat32 filesystem, which does not allow `:` character in filenames.
By the way you don't need to check for existence before using `mkdirs()`.